# How to set location of instance objects randomly along input mesh's polygon normal?

Tags: animation-nodes

i would like to ask about animation nodes.

first, i prepared a cube with loop animation along z axis.

and also sphere which its vertices locations will be position of instanced cube.

and i connected nodes like first picture.

.

what i want to do is randomize animation along the polygon normal of the sphere.(second picture)

i tried this way but it moves only along world z.(third picture)

i wish for advice.  thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scale polygon center location with random numbers or number wiggle for animation.

[image]

**Node tree:**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much.